# Redirecting users to nearest region backend server through single domain

Tags: dns, redirection, windows-server

Is there any way to redirect user which browse through a domain and then system/tool will auto redirect the traffic to nearest region? Maybe through some tools alike Tomcat, IIS or Load Balancer etc.

Example:

```
User A from USA surf to aaa.com will auto redirected traffic to USA server aaa.us.com
User B from NZD surf to aaa.com will auto redirected traffic to NZD server aaa.nzd.com
```

In short, one domain/dns to handle multiple region users.

Answer (score 0):

Use GeoDNS.  https://ns1.com/resources/how-geographic-routing-works

Most reputable DNS providers offer it, or roll your own using BIND/PowerDNS/etc.